# NetOffice ExcelAPI Causing 500 Error

Tags: .net, excel, server-error, netoffice

I have a web application that uses NetOffice ExcelAPI. All works okay on the local development machine, but when I deploy the application to the server and run the app I get a 500 error.  The log file doesn't seem to register that such an event has occurred but, by process of elimination, I have determined it is the NetOffice ExcelAPI that triggers the 500 error.

Interestingly, I have another web app on the same server using the same version of NetOffice.ExcelAPI that runs without any issues.

Can anyone offer any troubleshooting tips that might provide some light on why I get the 500 error.

Comment: This questions has a few months, so I assume you resolved it already. My question to you would be: Why use NetOffice (and have to install Excel on the server) instead using **ClosedXML** (https://closedxml.codeplex.com) or similar (that doesn't require Excel)?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Caio. I will test ClosedXML to see if that resolves the issue.